# Unicode Decode Error:invalid start byte

Tags: image, unicode, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, decision-tree

The purpose of the code is to create a **graph** for the **decision tree model**.
The code is given below.

```
dot_data=StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf,out_file=dot_data)
graph=py.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
print(graph)
Image.open(graph.create_png(),mode='r')
```

On execution, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Ankur/Python36/Python Files/Decision_Tree.py", line 58, in <module>
Image.open(graph.create_png(),mode='r')
File "C:\Ankur\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2477, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: 
invalid start byte
```

I am having a hard time to resolve this error as I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

`create_png()` returns a `bytes` object while `Image.open` (from [PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open)) expects a filename or file object.

Try

```
import io
Image.open(io.BytesIO(graph.create_png()))
```

and it should work